# Need consistent horizontal spacing between images

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am generating the following HTML for each row of [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV63O.jpg):

```
<div class='row signup'>
  <div class='col-md-1'>
    <span class='plus-icon'>
      <img alt="Plus" src="/assets/plus.jpg" width="18" height="18" />
    </span>
    <span class='minus-icon'>
      <img alt="Minus" src="/assets/minus.jpg" width="18" height="18" />
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-2'><input type="text" value="Food" name="sheet[slots_attributes][1][label]" id="sheet_slots_attributes_1_label" /></div>
  <div class='col-md-2'><input type="text" value="" name="sheet[slots_attributes][1][name]" id="sheet_slots_attributes_1_name" /></div>
  <div class='col-md-2'><input type="text" value="foo@foo.com" name="sheet[slots_attributes][1][email]" id="sheet_slots_attributes_1_email" /></div>
  <div class='col-md-2'><input type="text" value="3335557777" name="sheet[slots_attributes][1][phone]" id="sheet_slots_attributes_1_phone" /></div>
  <div class='col-md-2'><input type="text" value="" name="sheet[slots_attributes][1][comments]" id="sheet_slots_attributes_1_comments" /></div>
</div>
```

In the image, the top two rows are generated in jQuery (on click of the `+` buttons) and the bottom two rows render with the page.  I would like the `+` and `-` buttons/icons to be spaced as they are on original page render, but can't make it happen for the jQuery generated rows.

I believe that the issue is that the originally rendered rows (in Rails/HAML btw, although I think that is not important) include extra spacing from line feeds etc. while there is no extra spacing in the jQuery rows.  So in a sense, the jQuery rows are "correct", just not aesthetic.  Note that the HTML for both cases looks identical in Firebug.

What is the best way to ensure consistent horizontal spacing in both cases?  I think I need to style the `spans` or `imgs` in some way, but I am stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with padding. If it doesn't work, try with margin

```
<img alt="Plus" src="/assets/plus.jpg" width="18" height="18" style="padding:5px;"/>
```

You can also use padding-left, padding-top... if you want it to affect only at one side

Comment: Using `style="margin-right:4px; margin-top:1px;"` on the plus image and `style="margin-top:1px;"` on the minus image in the jQuery works in FF and Chrome but feels pretty brittle.  It seems like these numbers are somewhat arbitrarily tied to how browsers deal with line feeds and such.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to add a class directly to your plus/minus buttons.

```
<img class="row-signup-button" alt="Plus" src="/assets/plus.jpg" width="18" height="18" />
```

Then, you can use CSS padding-right to space the buttons out:

```
.row-signup-button {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle to show how it looks:  http://jsfiddle.net/0gj9ahun/

Comment: I don't think padding will work.  It will just shrink my images.

Comment: Hi Steve, I updated the JSFiddle with some actual icon images.  If you take a look you can see that padding-right causes the second icon to be pushed to the right:  http://jsfiddle.net/0gj9ahun/1/

Comment: Thanks for trying but someone with my icons they get shrunk with padding (just tried).  I think I'll stick with margin.